# SQL - The multi-part identifier "LargerPDFTest.pdf" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, sql-update

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spc_UpdateProductPDFCase]
    @ProdId int,
    @ProdModifiedDate DateTime,
    @ProdModifiedBy nvarchar(50) ='',
    @ColumnInput nvarchar(MAX),
    @File nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product
    SET
        ProdModifiedBy = @ProdModifiedBy,
        ProdModifiedDate = @ProdModifiedDate
    WHERE ProductID = @ProdId

    --Split up for troubleshooting
    Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE Product
                SET '
                    + @ColumnInput + ' = ' + @File +
                ' WHERE ProductID =  ' + cast(@ProdId AS nvarchar(max))

    execute sp_executesql @sql
END
```

This is an update statement for 4 PDF uploaders on an admin panel of an internal site. The site passes this stored procedure 1 column name (`@ColumnInput`), and file name eg: `Filename.pdf` (`@File`). When I test the upload I am given an error stating the file can not be bound.

> The multi-part identifier "LargerPDFTest.pdf" could not be bound.

My preference would be to do the update without using dynamic SQL, but I've not had luck with other routs either (such as case statements).

Edit: Forgot to mention that I only have 2 statements here for troubleshooting purposes. I will eventually be combining the two once I fix the issues I am having.

Comment: what is the value of @ColumnInput parameter?

Comment: @ColumnInput is the name of the column, in this case its passing in "ProdOptV12", "ProdOptV13", "ProdOptV14", or "ProdOptV15" depending on which uploader it's hitting. I'm still learning SQL so I wasn't sure if it's a problem that it's passing it in as a string.

Comment: Why are you passing the column to update as a parameter? This is wide open to sql injection attack.

Comment: Yes Barix, passing in a column name and executing that type of dynamic sql is a huge problem. Look up sql injection, your code is very vulnerable.

Comment: Sean, I am well aware of this and even stated that a better solution would be preferable. However it is an internal site, with well scrubbed inputs on the program side, so I will take what I can get.

Comment: @Sean Lange Thank you for letting me know though. I know Dynamic SQL is very unsecure and it is far from my first choice. I will continue to look into ways to make it a little more secure but for now this will have to do.

Comment: It can be made secure by parameterizing your dynamic sql. See my response in the answer I posted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this that is more safe. It is still using dynamic sql but the values are now parameterized.

```
SET @sql = 'UPDATE Product 
SET ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnInput) + ' = @File 
WHERE ProductID =  @ProdId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@File nvarchar(50), @ProdID int', @File = @File, @ProdID = @ProdID
```

Comment: I will give this a try in a few moments, I definitely wont turn away a more secure option :)